# " The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language. "

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to run tkinter  in my notebook, that has windows system, that is the problem I had, all the times that i tried
That is the problem i found!

I wanna run tkinter modules in my Python app.

Answer (score 2):

> The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.

is an error message from PowerShell, not Python.

Make sure you're entering code into the Python interpreter, not the PowerShell `PS` command line.